# return matching word in python

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a script that is checking if values in 'Product content' sheet (column 'TITLE') match with values from 'Keyword list' sheet, column 'KEYWORD' (the same workbook) . Compare_title function returns true or false which is ok but I also need to know which keywords are matching so not only true/false output but also the word that is considered as 'True match'.

The Python script is below.

```
import pandas as pd
import re


file_path ='C:/Users/User/Desktop/data.xlsx'


def get_keyword(file_path):
    """
    Get keywords that are active (based on value in column 'ACTIVE?') from 'KEYWORD' column
    from 'Hidden search' terms sheet and convert it into the list
    """
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Keyword list')
    keywords = df['KEYWORD'].to_list()

    return keywords


keyword_list = get_keyword(file_path)


def words(phrase: str) -> [str]:
    """
    Splits string to words by all characters that are not letters or digits (spaces, commas etc.)
    """

    return list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), filter(len, re.split(r'\W', phrase))))


def compare_title(file_path):
    """
    Get title from 'Product content' sheet and compare the values with keyword_list values
    """

    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Product content')
    df = df.fillna('-')
    title = df['TITLE'].apply(lambda find_kw: any([keyword in words(find_kw) for keyword in keyword_list]))

    return title
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
title = df['TITLE'].apply(lambda find_kw: [keyword for keyword in keyword_list if keyword in words(find_kw)]))
```

This means `compare_title` will return `list[str]` instead of `bool`. If you do `if compare_title(...)` it still works as before because an empty list is falsy and a non-empty list is truthy.